# Create a basic auto-complete suggestion list

Tags: php, autocomplete, search-engine, autosuggest

How can I create an auto-complete suggestion list below the search box that:

1. Users can use keyboard `Down` & `Up` key to navigate between them?
2. Users can use `Esc` button to close the suggestion list?
3. When users press keyboard `Down` or `Up` key, the suggestion that is selected will be filled inside the search box?

This is my current code for index.php:

```
<?php
include 'script_suggestion.php';
include 'script_close_suggestion_box.php';
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Brandon's Search Engine
        </title>
        <style type="text/css">
            #suggestion {
                border: 1px solid black;
                visibility: hidden;
                position: absolute;
                background-color: white;
                z-index: 10;
            }
            #suggestion a {
                font-size: 12pt;
                color: black;
                text-decoration: none;
                display: block;
                width: 648px;
                height: auto;
                text-align: left;
                padding: 2px;
            }
            #suggestion a:hover {
                background-color: #dddddd;
                width: 644px;
                padding: 2px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="GET" action="search.php" name="q">
            <table align="center">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <h1><center>Brandon's Search Engine</center></h1>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center">
                        <input type="text" name="q" style="height: 27px; width: 650px; padding: 2px" placeholder="Search Now"
                               onkeyup="getSuggestion(this.value)" autocomplete="off" onblur="closeBox()"/>

                        <div id="suggestion" style="width: 648px">
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center">
                        <input type="submit" value="Search" style="height: auto; width: 60px; padding: 2px" />
                        <input type="reset" value="Clear" onclick="closeBox()" style="height: auto; width: 50px; padding: 2px" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center">
                        Can't find your site? <br /> Insert <a href="insert.php">here</a>.
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <input type="hidden" name="page" value="1" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: I have tried that but I do not know how to use that in my code.

Comment: Show us how u tried, and we can make suggestions on it from there

Comment: http://pastebin.com/Ri8715Gc

Comment: @Rob I have get you my suggestion code. Can you help me now?

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Jquery UI AutoComplete, here is the example code

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script>
  $(function() {

  var availableTags = [
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp",
      "BASIC",
      "C",
      "C++",
      "Clojure",
      "COBOL",
      "ColdFusion",
      "Erlang",
      "Fortran",
      "Groovy",
      "Haskell",
      "Java",
      "JavaScript",
      "Lisp",
      "Perl",
      "PHP",
      "Python",
      "Ruby",
      "Scala",
      "Scheme"
    ];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
  <input id="tags">
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Example taken from - http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

```
    /**
         This code below loads the autocomplete for your input field,
         where in "#tags" is the id of your element where this should
         be displayed in and "availableTags" is the array of list of
         possible values to be shown in autocomplete list
     */
     $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
```

If you want to fetch data dynamically through PHP that is stored in database, you may want to use http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote